# How to search array from last index?

Tags: c++, arrays, search

My program is suppose to replicate the memory management function Next-fit. Essentially my program is suppose to have a job and a partition. It will check to see if the job is less than or equal to the partition size. If it is less than or equal to then the job is stored. A value (index) should hold in which partition the job was stored in last and starts searching from that location.

Problem: I do not know how to continuously call the search from the where the last job was stored.

```
void  Partition::nextFit(Job *job, Partition *partitionArray, int partitionArraySize, int numberOfJobs)
{
    Partition temp;
    int Next;
    int index;
    //loops the amount of jobs
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfJobs; i++)
    {
        //job less than or = partition
        if (job[i].jobSize <= partitionArray[i].size)
        {
            //partition =  partition - job
            partitionArray[i].size = partitionArray[i].size -job[i].jobSize;
            cout << "Unused space (Hole): " << partitionArray[i].size << "Kb" << endl;
            cout << endl;

        }
        //index becomes the location of where the last job was stored
        index = i;

        //relaunch loop to search from point index
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `index` in your `for` loop instead of `i`?

Comment: If I use index instead of i wouldn't the loop be infinite    (int index =0; index<numberOfJobs;? (index) (index++)) @ThomasMatthews

Comment: @maulinrodriguez _`//relaunch loop to search from point index`_ I don't understand what you actually want here? You are at this point already, so what do you mean with _relaunch_?

Comment: What I mean is for example Job1 : 200kb Job2 : 300kb Job4 : 100kb Job5 : 200kb   and the partitions are  Part1:300 part2:200 part3: 400 part4:100    In this case job 1 will to to part 1 job 2 will go to part 3 job 3 will go to part 4 job 4 will have to go to part 2.    So far it has accessed the array sub 0,2, and 3. If I leave my loop the way it is it will break after the forth loop. When the program gets to job 4 it has to go back to array sub 0, again then to 1 and store job 4 in 1. @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @maulinrodriguez Given your description, did you write out a plan on how to accomplish this before you started writing code?

Comment: @maulinrodriguez - Your loop would probably be more easily visualized if you just changed to a `while (true)` and `break` out of the loop when you determine you don't need to loop any further.  All of those other variables you mentioned are set appropriately within the loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes so far my First-fit, Best-fit, and Worst-fit work according to what I wrote before coding. Next-fit I sort of did not understand fully in the beginning. After searched up its definition I tried writing this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you! I have just figured it out. I can just make a loop. Once it reached the end of the array as long as it is not full restart the search for free partitions. :)

Comment: @maulinrodriguez Good.  Usually, this is the approach to take if the loop constraints and/or exit conditions are complex.  Start out with an unbounded loop, code the logic within the loop, just to get something working.  Later on refactor to see if indeed a regular `for` loop or set of `for` loops (or maybe usage of some STL algorithm functions) would work instead of the unbounded loop.  If not, leave the unbounded loop alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void  Partition::nextFit(Job *job, Partition *partitionArray, int partitionArraySize, int numberOfJobs)
{
    int j = 0;
    int count=0;
    int locationOfMemory;

//finds the largest partition
    int maxsize = partitionArray[0].size;

    for (int l = 0; l < partitionArraySize; l++)
    {
        if (maxsize <= partitionArray[l].size)
        {
            maxsize = partitionArray[l].size;
        }
    }


//loops the amount of jobs

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfJobs; i++)
    {
        if (job[i].jobSize < maxsize)
        {
            //job less than or = partition
            if (job[i].jobSize <= partitionArray[j].size)
            {
                locationOfMemory = j+1;
                //partition =  partition - job
                cout << "Job: " << i + 1 << " was allocated in Partition: " << locationOfMemory<< endl;
                partitionArray[j].size = partitionArray[j].size - job[i].jobSize;
                cout << "Unused space (Hole): " << partitionArray[j].size << "Kb" << endl;
                cout << endl;
                if (j != partitionArraySize - 1)
                {
                    j++;
                }
                else
                {
                    j = 0;
                }

            }
            else
            {    //if the job is larger than the partition stay at the current job and increment the partition index to the next one
                i = i - 1;
                j = j + 1;
                }
        }
         else
        {
            cout << "Job" << "is too big and cannot be allocated" << endl;
        }
    }
//partition busy or not
    for (int m = 0; m < partitionArraySize; m++)
    {

         if (partitionArray[m].size == 0)
        {
            count = m + 1;
            cout << "Partition # " << count << " Status: Busy" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            count = m + 1;
            cout << "Partition # " << count << " Status: Free" << endl;
        }
    }


}
```